# Bootstrap 5 and Nuxt3 and OffCanvas: Why does the backdrop not darken when toggled?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use  the Bootstrap 5 [Offcanvas component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/) with Nuxt3. I have the offcanvas working, but does anyone know why the dark "backdrop" is not shown? The example I am trying to emulate is here: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/bu3k9l?file=index.html**

But, my attempt is here (notice the background of the page does not darken like the above example when I open the sidebar/offcanvas component: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zqzl4k?file=components/OffCanvas.vue**

My `OffCanvas.vue` code:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="offcanvas offcanvas-start"
    :class="showMenu ? 'show' : ''"
    tabindex="-1"
    id="offcanvasExample"
    :style="{ visibility: showMenu ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"
  >
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
      <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">
        Offcanvas with backdrop
      </h5>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close text-reset"
        @click.prevent="$emit('show-menu')"
      ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
      <p>.....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  showMenu: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: The first link is 404.

Comment: sorry! Fixed now. Can you take a look again?